# c++ constructor with default argument

Tags: c++

Hello I made this class that has a default constructor and a constructor with default argument

```
Something.h

class Something  // Fraction class
{
public:
      Something (void); // default ctor
      Something (int xx, int yy = 1 );
          int x,y; 
}
```

---

Something.cpp

```
Something::Something(){}

Something::Something(int xx, int yy)
{
    x = xx;
    y = yy;
}
```

but when I make object with no parameter and print it, it will show that x = 0, y = 0;

where might be the problem :( 
Thanks!

Comment: what constructor are you calling? the first one or the second? maybe you are calling the first one...

Comment: anyway, try to use initializers like this in the second constructor: `Something::Something(int xx, int yy): x(xx), y(yy) {}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call with no parameters, you will be calling this constructor

```
Something::Something(){}
```

instead of this

```
Something::Something(int xx, int yy)
```

so your initialisation code wont get called as you have provided none explicitly and you will get a default value upon initialisation of your integer members - in this case it was zero, but it **could** be any integer value. For this reason it is good practice to initialise your member variables in the constructor implementation. For example implementing it like this

```
Something::Something() : x(1),y(1) {}
```

will result in `x` and `y` being set to 1 when you create an instance of your object with the zero argument constructor.

Comment: This is correct, except for the zero initialization. See the comments to other answers.

Comment: @juanchopanza Updated the relevant parts. I was not implying that the zero initialisation was a general occurrence just that it was obviously happening in the OP code (for whatever reason). However, I can see that the way that it was written did not perhaps make this clear enough so I have emphasised that part

Answer (score 8):

When you make an object with no arguments, you call the default constructor:

```
Something::Something(){}
```

This one **does not** initialize `x` or `y`, which means you could get any value that fits in an `int`. Presumably you are using a debug configuration, so you get `x` and `y` initialized to `0`. Whatever the reason, you should not count on that behaviour.

To invoke the constructor with the default argument, you need to call it with one or two arguments:

```
Something s1(5);
Something s2(5,6);
```

**Edit** if you want to make sure your default constructor zero-initializes `x` and `y`, you can do so explicitly in the initialization list:

```
Something::Something() : x(0), y(0) {}
```

Comment: Can you post some reference that default value is not `0` for `int`s?

Comment: @Azodious see [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) §8.5.6.

Comment: In C++11, 12.6.2/8 says that the non-static data members of non-class type are default-initialized, since they don't appear in any *mem-initializer-list*. 8.5/6 says that default-initializing an `int` performs no initialization.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this problem is that you have written the overloaded constructor for this and but you calling the constructor with no parameters so the by default the default constructor is being called and no assignment happens to your variables.

You have to pass the arguments for inorder to invoke the overloaded constructor. You overloaded constructor have assigned default value of 1 to yy so if you just simply pass one argument xx will be assigned that value and yy will have the default value of 1 in this case. But if you will pass the two arguments the xx and yy will be assigned those values respectively.

Answer (score -1):

> when I make object with no parameter and print it, it will show that x = 0, y = 0;

By default, the instance fields are initialized to their default value. For `int` data-type the default value is `0`

Comment: That's not a good practice though - always initialize your data before usage.

Comment: That is not correct, the `int`s would not get initialized to `0` here.

Comment: @icepack: it will be redundant if you are initializing to default value only.

Comment: @juanchopanza: well, why not? how will you prove it?

Comment: @Azodious I would look it up in the standard, which unfortunately I cannot do right now. But GCC produces a nice uninitialized variables warning if I try to use `x` or `y`.